# How to prevent google translate V2, to change the format of dates using c# client

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I have a problem related to Google Translate.
I am using Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 in c# application
following code can re produce the problem I am facing

```
var client = TranslationClient.Create(Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"keyFile.json"));
            string textToTranslate = @"نود إفادتكم بأننا حضرنا جلسة اليوم وحضر المدعى عليه وطلبت من المحكمة أجل أخير للتسوية ووافقت المحكمة على تأجيل الدعوى كأجل أخير لتاريخ 12/10/2023م للتسوية أو الرد";
            string textToLang = @"en";
            string textFromLang = @"ar";
            string translatedTextReturn = string.Empty;

            TranslationResult translationResult = client.TranslateText(textToTranslate, textToLang, textFromLang, TranslationModel.ServiceDefault);

            translatedTextReturn = translationResult.TranslatedText;

            Console.WriteLine(translatedTextReturn);

            Console.ReadLine();
```

translatedTextReturn = "We would like to inform you that we attended today's session and the defendant attended, and I asked the court for a deadline for settlement, and the court agreed to postpone the case as a deadline for **10/12/2023** AD for settlement or response"

as you see I have the dd/MM/yyyy format for dates but translated text automatically converts to MM/dd/yyyy

How could I prevent this?
Thanks

Comment: If the API does not provide a switch or option for keeping date formats, then you cannot. Dates and times will typically be transformed into the culture specific formats during translation. You could try and replace dates with a reformatted value after translation, of course.

Comment: I understand and searched a lot for the option you mentioned, I think I will end up to keep the dates stored in some list and send some special placeholder which hopefully not translate and replace after translation

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me. Maybe write that as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Hi  @AliAdnan,You can consider using a html tag (<span translate="no"> 12/10/2023 </span>) to prevent google translation api from translating a specific part of the sentence .By using a html cleaner we can remove html tag from the translated text.

Comment: Hi kiran,
I am getting text from database as I mentioned in question, extracting date and surrounded by span is some how difficult for me, I am try to translate as it is and after translation I am swiping MM/dd part to dd/MM still I am facing some challenges but any how thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

*Posting the above comment as an answer to help community members in their research.*

As I mentioned above comment, as a workaround you can consider using  html `<span translate="no"></span>` tag (`<span translate="no"> 12/10/2023 </span>`) to prevent google translation api from translating a specific part of the sentence .By using a html cleaner we can remove html tag from the translated text

***I replicated it in python and  I got the expected output. If you are flexible to use python then you can try the below code.***

**Example:**

```
import re
CLEANR = re.compile('<.*?>') 
def translate_text(target: str,source:str, text: str) -> dict:

    from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
    translate_client = translate.Client()

    if isinstance(text, bytes):
        text = text.decode("utf-8")
    result = translate_client.translate(text, target_language=target,source_language=source)
    a=re.sub(CLEANR, '', result["translatedText"])
    print(f'Translation: {a}')
    return result

a=translate_text('en','ar','نود إعلامكم بأننا حضرنا جلسة اليوم وحضر المدعى عليه ، وطلبت من المحكمة تحديد موعد نهائي للتسوية ، ووافقت المحكمة على تأجيل القضية كموعد نهائي لـ <span translate = "no"> 12/10 / 2023 </span> م للتسوية أو الرد')
```

**RESULT**

[image]

As per the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate) there are currently no options to selectively skip translations for sections of text. If you want this feature to be implemented, you can open a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker.For more information you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text).